# How to parse this sentence with "not only……but also"? I wonder whether it is a fixed sentence pattern

Tags: sentence-construction

> When you read, you can ***not only*** learn some new words, ***but also***
>   you can learn how to use these English words.

I thought the sentence should be :

> "When you read, not only you can learn some new words, but also you
>   can learn how to use these English words.

or

> When you read,  you can not only learn some new words, but also 
>   learn how to use these English words.

What do "only" and "also" modify?

Comment: Also - *When you read, not only do you learn some new words, but also their usage.*

Answer (score 2):

The first suggested alternative is not grammatically correct. The possible orderings of "you can not only" are:

- "you can not only"
- "not only can you"

Also, there are not strict limitations on how much of the second clause you may/must repeat. The following are all grammatical:

> "you can not only verb *object A*, but also you can verb *object B*"
>   "you can not only verb *object A*, but also verb *object B*"
>   "you can not only verb *object A*, but also *object B*"

All these sentences would be correct with either "not only can you" or "you can not only".

Comment: What about *you not only can*? (The "you" would not get repeated in this case). I think it's only the "not only" that can't be split, no?

Comment: @starsplusplus yes I would say "you not only can" is grammatical, but clunkier sounding than the others.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I agree.

Comment: Are the following grammatically correct? 1) Not only can you write this way, but also you're encouraged to. 2) Not only can you write this way, but you also are encouraged to. 3) Not only can you write this way, but you're also encouraged to. 4) Not only can you write this way, but also are encouraged to.

Comment: Only your second example is grammatically correct. The rest violate parallel structure.

Comment: @lerner #2 and 3 are correct. #1 isn't used too much since it doesn't flow off the tongue as nicely, but it's still correct. #4 is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

The given sentence itself is wrong. Your two alternatives are perfectly grammatically correct, save for a little error which we'll get to later.

"Not only... but also" is an example of a **correlative conjunction**. And when using correlative conjunctions, you have to make both parts of the conjunction **parallel**, meaning you have to make sure both parts have equal grammatical units. See [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/parallelstructure.htm) for more on parallelism.

For example, here's the given sentence:

> When you read, you can *not only* {learn some new words}, *but also* {you can learn how to use these English words}.

You can easily see that the two {parts} aren't equal, or parallel. Here are some fixed versions, with the parallelisms sorted out:

> When you read, you can *not only* {learn some new words}, *but also* {learn how to use these English words}.
>
> When you read, you can learn *not only* {some new words}, *but also* {how to use these English words}.
>
> When you read, *not only* {can you learn some new words}, *but* {you can *also* learn how to use these English words}.

You may have noticed that with the third one, the word order is kinda changed around, and this is the little error in your first alternative.

If you introduce an independent clause with "not only...," the clause has to be inverted, hence the "not only can you" instead of "not only you can." It's just how it is.

As for "but you can also" word order, the adverb "also" has to come *after* "be" or helping verbs. For more info about adverb placement, see [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/AdverbPl.html).

Cheers.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this. Parallel structure is basic stuff—you learn this in grade school, and it's a favorite topic among SAT/ACT questions. If it's not parallel, it's not grammatical.

Comment: "If it's not parallel, it's not grammatical" is not entirely correct. Parallelism is a style preference, not a division between grammatical and ungrammatical usage. Plenty of native speakers say and write non-parallel structures all the time.

Comment: @nohat Plenty of native speakers also speak and write in incorrect grammar, no matter the language.